# How to create header and footer using angular material

Tags: header, angular-material, angular6, footer

I am trying to create header and footer using angular material, can anyone please guide me how to do this or please share me any examples to design this.

Html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<span>Header</span>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-card>@Copyright2019</mat-card>
```

Css

```
    .mat-card{
        color:white;
        background-color: #303F9F;
        border-radius: 0px;
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
   .mat-toolbar{
   margin-bottom:875px;
}
```

I have created header and footer. I have used margin-bottom to maintain gap between header and footer. Please find the below link to view screenshot.
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/5535/XThUEX.png

Is there any other way to get responsive header and footer using angular6 material.

Comment: Share what have you tried?

Comment: for admin app or website, show code